# Allow only selected charcters based on regex in an EditText

Tags: android, regex, user-input, validation, android-edittext

I want to allow users only to type certain characters based on the a regex in my android applications. How do I achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How can I validate EditText input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input). See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151664).

Comment: Based on a regex? Do you mean just a list of allowed characters? That's not a regex.

Comment: @Falmarri This is it - [[\\d]\\,\\+]*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Used a `TextWatcher` as @Matt Ball suggested.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      String text = s.toString();
      int length = text.length();

      if(length > 0 && !Pattern.matches(PATTERN, text)) {
           s.delete(length - 1, length);
      }
}
```

**Edit**
Although the `TextWatcher` works, it would be cleaner to use an `InputFilter`. Check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12656159/421372).

Comment: This helped me a lot, thanks I just got a problem when the user deleted a character and it didn't enter the PATTERN was crashing because an out of bounds so you can use this (with some modifications for my app)

if(text.length()>0) {
                        int length = text.length();
                        if (!getPattern().equals("")) {
                            if (!Pattern.matches(getPattern(),text)) {
                                s.delete(length - 1, length);
                            }
                        }
}

Answer (score 2):

You could use `android:digits` on the xml EditText instead of using a regex.

For your allowed chars of the regex (numbers, comma and plus symbol):
`android:digits="0123456789,+"`

And you could use a string resource as the digits value in case you want to reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: If the character to type matches /[a-zA-Z0-9{insert valid characters here}]/ then allow it, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `InputFilter` for advanced filtering:

```
class CustomInputFilter : InputFilter {

  private val regex = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9]*$")

  override fun filter(
    source: CharSequence,
    start: Int,
    end: Int,
    dest: Spanned?,
    dstart: Int,
    dend: Int
  ): CharSequence? {
    val matcher = regex.matcher(source)
    return if (matcher.find()) {
      null
    } else {
      ""
    }
  }
}
```

And then add it to an `EditText` or `TextInputEditText` like this:

```
textInputLayout.editText!!.filters += CustomInputFilter()
//or
editText.filters += CustomInputFilter()
```

Remember that if you have a `TextWatcher` this will not prevent the `TextWatcher` to fire, you can filter out those events checking if the previous and next text values are the same.

Something like:

```
//addTextChangedListener is an extension function available in core-ktx library
textInputLayout.editText!!.addTextChangedListener(afterTextChanged = { editable ->
  val editTextValue = viewModel.editTextLiveData.value ?: ""
  if (!editTextValue.equals(editable)) {
    viewModel.updateEditTextValue(editable?.toString() ?: "")
  }
})
```

Comment: from your first line: You can use an `IntentFilter` for advanced filtering:
It should be `InputFilter` right?

Comment: @ShailendraMadda Yes it was a typo. I fixed it now, thank you :)