# EditText max size to integer and decimal

Tags: android, regex

I need set max input of integer (7), and max inut of decimal (2). Example: 7777777.77, at this moment I' using Regex for integer, but how can I set input user for decimal??

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(7) });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic regex pattern would be

```
^[0-9]{1,7}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

However if your regex engine supports negative lookahead and you want to prevent unwanted leading zeros, such as `000123.45`, then use pattern

```
^(?!0[0-9])[0-9]{1,7}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

And if you want to allow numbers with decimal point and no traling numbers, such as `123.`, then replace `{1,2}` part with `{0,2}`.

Comment: how can set the EditText to you regex? How is the sintax

Comment: @ale : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180770/allow-only-selected-charcters-based-on-regex-in-an-edittext : PATTERN syntax is `/pattern/`