# Empty Field and other Validations in android

Tags: android, validation

Is there any built-in method available in Android for validations like Email validation, empty string validation etc..??

Comment: Can you elaborate on "etc"? Also, empty string validation?! What more other than `String.length() == 0` do you need?

Comment: thanks... I would like to know the number validations too..

Comment: and also the E-mail validations..

Comment: Following link may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151664/how-to-make-validation-on-edit-text

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in validation in Android, you could just use common Java helper classes, which are to be found on the web I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the apache validator lib. But if you like, I have written a very easy to understand validation library. Free to download and use.

You can find it here: [Android field validation](http://dekwant.eu/?p=138)

Here a code sample:

```
new CheckBoxRequiredValidator(myCheckbox, "This checkbox is required"); // To validate checkboxes
new RegExpressionValidator(_armyName, getString(R.string.charRegularExpression),
getString(R.string.armyNameValidation), getString(R.string.illegalexpression)); // Regex validation
```

The regular expressing and the error message is in `strings.xml`

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText name1,address1,mobile,adhar,pincod,email_id;
  Button submit,forget;
  String em;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    address1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
    mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
    adhar=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.adhar_no);
    pincod=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pincode);
    email_id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intilize();
            if (!validation()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"sucessfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        private boolean validation() {

            boolean valid=true;
            if (name1.getText().toString().isEmpty()||name1.getText().length()<6){
                name1.setError("invalid name");

                valid=false;
            }
              if (address1.getText().toString().isEmpty()||address1.getText().length()>10){
                  address1.setError("wrong address");
                  valid=false;
              }
               if (mobile.getText().length()!=10){
                   mobile.setError("incorrect number");
                   valid=false;
               }
                        if (em.isEmpty()|| !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(em).matches()){
                            email_id.setError("wrong email id");

                        }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

  private void intilize() {
      em=email_id.getText().toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged!