# How to ensure user fill all EditText

Tags: android

I have EditText where it will save to SQlite database. It is running fine. But my problem is when the user didn't fill any of the EditText, the apps will crash. The apps will still run if atleast one of the edittext is filled. But still, how can I avoid the crash and prompt the user to fill all of the EditText if they fail to do so.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{
EditText e_name, e_numb, e_pangkat, e_tarikh, e_masa, e_peny, e_peg;
String name, numb, pangkat, tarikh, masa, peny, peg;

private DBOperations db;
private EditText fromDateEtxt;
private EditText toTimeEtxt;
private int mHour, mMinute;

private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
private TimePickerDialog toTimePickerDialog;

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DBOperations(this);
    e_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    e_numb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numbTent);
    e_pangkat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pangkat);
    e_tarikh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tarikh);
    e_masa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.masa);
    e_peny = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.penyelia);
    e_peg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pegawai);

    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
    findViewsById();
    setDateTimeField();

}
public void saveData(View view)
{
    name = e_name.getText().toString();
    numb = e_numb.getText().toString();
    pangkat = e_pangkat.getText().toString();
    tarikh = e_tarikh.getText().toString();
    masa = e_masa.getText().toString();
    peny = e_peny.getText().toString();
    peg = e_peg.getText().toString();



    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute("add_info", name, numb, pangkat, tarikh, masa, peny, peg);
    finish();

    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChecklistType.class);
    startActivity(i);

}


private void findViewsById() {
    fromDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tarikh);
    fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();

    toTimeEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.masa);
    toTimeEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
}

private void setDateTimeField() {
    fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    toTimeEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    toTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {

                    e_masa.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == fromDateEtxt) {
        fromDatePickerDialog.show();
    } else if(view == toTimeEtxt) {
        toTimePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

my LogCat:

```
04-20 09:14:20.573 21073-21280/com.example.hp.semakoperasimampatansrc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                                        Process: com.example.hp.semakoperasimampatansrc, PID: 21073
                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                            at com.example.hp.semakoperasimampatansrc.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:38)
                                                                                            at com.example.hp.semakoperasimampatansrc.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:13)
                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: what error you get when app crashed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty Field and other Validations in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301099/empty-field-and-other-validations-in-android)

Comment: I've put my logcat. I also just realized the crash only happened when user didnt put any input in the editText but it will still run if they fill one of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that edit text is containing any string or not by checking isempty like below code

```
 if(!e_name.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        //perform your work 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the editText is filled by using **TextUtils** class.

Example:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cannot empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code for ur all editText

```
    if (name .length() <= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill this field",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if string is empty or not 
`e_numb.getText().toString().equals("")
OR
e_numb.getText().toString().isEmpty();`