# Take only one character from user in Android

Tags: android, char, character, letter

I want user to enter just one character. I thought to make buttons for every letter, but this is useless. Could you recommend something to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could among other solutions make a field and set your event handler to only accept one character at the time.

This is very close to that question: [Validation on Edit Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151664/how-to-make-validation-on-edit-text)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [InputFilter.LengthFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.LengthFilter.html) to limit the number of characters that can be entered into a text field and a custom [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) to restrict the characters that are allowed; which sounds like the simplest approach to me.

Here's an example:

```
EditText myTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_text);

InputFilter validCharsInputFilter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            // Loop through characters being inserted
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

                // If it is not a letter 
                if (!Character
                        .isLetter(source.charAt(i))) {

                    // Return empty string - as char not allowed
                    return "";
                }
            }

            // If we've got this far, then return null to accept string
            return null;
        }
    };

myTextField.setFilters(
        new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1), validCharsInputFilter });
```